# Relation between mother an child

Tags: java, relationship, java-17

I have 2 classes : Mother  and Child  +  ofcourse an Main.
Class Mother:

```
public class Mother extends Child {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Mother(int id, String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mother{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Class Child:

```
public class Child {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Child(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Child() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Child{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I have to make a relation  between the classes  that a mother can have  many childs but a child can have
only  one mother .

So in  main I read(the file.txt witch contains the name, age and id for mother and name  and age fro child)and parse it
Main:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Mother> mothers = mother();
        System.out.println(mothers);

        List<Child> child = child();
        System.out.println(child);
    }

    public static List<Mother> mother() throws IOException {
        List<Mother> mothers = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mom.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] s = line.split("\\s+");
            mothers.add(new Mother(Integer.parseInt(s[0]), s[1], Integer.parseInt(s[2])));
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return mothers;
    }
    public static List<Child> child() throws IOException {
        List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("child.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] s = line.split("\\s+");
            childs.add(new Child(s[0], Integer.parseInt(s[1])));
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return childs;
    }
}
```

Is there somoane that can give me an example of how I should to it or  where I  should start?

Comment: Start with learning about *inheritance*. When your `Mother` class extends the `Child` class, it inherits all members (fields and methods), hence, it has already a name and age. All related repetitions are obsolete and a potential source of inconsistencies. Then, how do you want to establish relationships between these two lists? Just randomly assign children to mothers?

Comment: Hey , 
 yes i need to asign randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a list of child on mother. By doing this a mother object will have many child and maintain a mother class ref. in child. will allow you to have a child only one mother.

Example:

```
class Mother{

    private List<Child> childList = new ArrayList<>();

    ....................................................
    ....................................................
}
```

```
class Child{

    private Mother mother;

    ....................................................
    ....................................................
}
```

BTW you should post what you have tried so far. Try reading about java collection.

Comment: Lines of code are added  and  also  some extra  i have to do  and i already did- read the files and parse it